# Vuetify: in a treeview slot, how to know at which depth I am in the tree?

Tags: vuetify.js

How, in a `<v-treeview>` slot, to know at which depth I am in the tree ?

```
<v-treeview :items="myItems" :open="open">
  <template v-slot:label="{ item, open, selected }">
    {{ item }}
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<v-treeview>` component in Vuetify will generate a `<v-treeview-node>` child component for each item in the `items` array. By creating a custom component and using it in the `label` slot of the `<v-treeview>` component, it's possible to access the props for that generated `<v-treeview-node>` component by accessing `this.$parent` inside the custom component. Each child component can get its depth value with `this.$parent.level`.

Check out my example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-browser-z4p5x?file=/src/components/ListItem.vue

Comment: how can I use it in my case ?